# Can't add object to NSMutableArray in singleton

Tags: ios, xcode6, singleton, nsmutablearray

I made a singleton and i'm trying to add objects to `self.timelineArray` but i can't. When i do this i have 9 objects:

```
NSNumber* nmb = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
[self.dataManager.timelineArray addObject:nmb];
```

After i insert the `nmb` object, i still have 9 objects.

Here's my singleton header (only important bits):

```
@interface DataManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* timelineArray;
```

Here's my singleton implementation (only important bits):

```
#import "DataManager.h"

static DataManager* sharedInstance = nil;

@implementation DataManager

+ (DataManager *) sharedInstance{

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedInstance == nil)
            sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {

    if (self = [super init])
    {    
        self.timelineArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is just simple coding and i can't seem to figure out why it does not work.

Comment: Is there a reason to get downvoted?

Comment: I don't believe so; the question is well asked.  +1 to counter.

Comment: And you get no exceptions?

Comment: Is any where in the code "self.timelineArray" gets reinitialized with NSArray object? Exception raised due to attempt of modifying immutable object!

Comment: Have you actually assigned a value to `self.dataManager`? I.e. `self.dataManager=[DataManager sharedInstance];`

Comment: I take it somewhere in the code you have `self.dataManager = [DataManager sharedInstance]`, before you call `[self.dataManager.timelineArray addObject:nmb];`

Comment: @vignesh i initialize the array with [dataManager setTimelineArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"timeline"]];

Comment: @HotLicks no exceptions

Comment: "Operation had no effect" is pretty much inevitably the result of doing the operation on a nil pointer.

Comment: Your `timeLineArray` property should be read only. Singletons are bad enough but arbitrarily allowing objects to replace the NSMutableArray instance in the singleton is very bad - or is the code you showed inside the singleton?  Regardless the object from a JSON response probably isn't mutable

Comment: Thats where the problem is, replace "[responseObject objectForKey:@"timeline"]" with [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"timeline"]] and check:)

Comment: @vignesh you were right! Noob mistake, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to modify immutable array(NSArray) will lead to this.

Replace 
`[responseObject objectForKey:@"timeline"]` with `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"timeline"]`

This was based on the comments of the question.

Answer (score 0):

i'll suggest you to add like following

```
NSNumber* nmb = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
[[DataManager sharedInstance]timelineArray addObject:nmb];
```

this will always add into the `singleton` not the `instance` of `singleton`